# Infragistics Ultralistview MouseHover Retrieve User Information

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, desktop-application, infragistics

I am using Infragistics Ultralistview to display data in List which contains 3 columns and 4-5 rows(that could be upto 'n' rows depending upon data added). When i hover over the row for 2 seconds, i want that other information about that row should be displayed in a panel like control. How to do that?

Let me know if anything else is required from my side.

Comment: UPDATE: I want MouseHover event on ListView's Item and not on ListView

Answer (score 0):

I've done this sort of thing with a Combo using the MouseEnterElement event from the control and processing the display of the extra information manually.

For my project specifically, I reference the data from a ValueListItem. When the event is triggered, it fires up an UltraWinToolTip for that dropdown element.

For your project, you might want to attribute your extra data to the Tag property of each UltraListViewItem, and capture the MouseEnterElement. Try something like (vb):

```
Dim lst As UltraListView = CType(sender, UltraListView)

If e.Element.GetContext().GetType() Is GetType(UltraListViewItem) Then
    '-- Get the item in question
    Dim li As UltraListViewItem = CType(e.Element.GetContext(), UltraListViewItem)
    '-- Transpose your own data here
    Dim dr As DataRow = CType(li.Tag, DataRow)
    '-- Use a timer to delay the showing of the tip, or just set the text here
End If
```

Afterwards, clean up by using `MouseLeaveElement`, doing something along the lines of:

```
If e.Element.GetContext().GetType() Is GetType(ValueListItem) Then
    '-- Get rid of the text
End If
```